# How do I show server validation errors to client? PostgreSQL, React, Node, Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks, express-validator

I would like to show my client why my server side Express Validator is refusing his inputs.  Specifically, I want to show him what's inside this line of code:

```
return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()});
```

I have struggled through other posts and videos for two days with no solutions.  Help please.
Here is the rest of my code for the POST loop:
Front End:

```
    const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {    
        e.preventDefault();     
        try {
            const body = { aName, aLastName, aPhone, aEmail, job1, jobDesc1, job2, jobDesc2, job3, jobDesc3, edu, eduYear, certTitle };
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/path", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });

            getApplicants();

        } catch (err) { 
            console.log('this line fires in catch block of client POST')
            console.error(err.message);
        }   
    };
```

Back End:

```
app.post("/path", 
    [
        check('aName')
        .trim().exists({checkFalsy: true}).withMessage('Name must be at least two letters long.').bail()
        .isLength({ min: 2 }).withMessage('Name must be at least two letters long.').bail()
        .isString().withMessage('Name must be letters with apostrophe or dash'),
        check('aEmail')
        .trim().isEmail().withMessage('Must be a valid email')
        .normalizeEmail().toLowerCase()
    ],
    async (req, res, next) => {
        const { aName, aLastName, aPhone, aEmail, job1, jobDesc1, job2, jobDesc2, job3, jobDesc3, edu, eduYear, certTitle } = req.body;
        console.log(req.body.aName);  // prints out exactly what it should
        
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        console.log(errors.array());
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()}); //This holds what I want to show!
        } else {

        try {
            const newApplicant = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO table
            ( applicantName, applicantLastName, applicantPhone, applicantEmail, jobTitle1, jobDesc1, jobTitle2, jobDesc2, jobTitle3, jobDesc3, educationTitle, educationYear, certificationTitle) 
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13) RETURNING *`,
                [aName, aLastName, aPhone, aEmail, job1, jobDesc1, job2, jobDesc2, job3, jobDesc3, edu, eduYear, certTitle]
            );
            
            res.json(newApplicant.rows[0]);  // "means accessing the first element in the array"
            // .rows is used to specify you JUST want rows, not a ton of other things that are in the response object.
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    }
});
```

I cannot get the information from the response object on to the screen to inform the client.  Best I've done is to save the response.json() in a state which prints to the f12 dev console as {errors: Array(2)} but I cannot get this printed out in JSX via any tech I know.
I do this with these lines inside the front end post method:

```
            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorHolder = await response.json();

                console.log(errorHolder); //{errors: Array(2)} 
                setErrors(errorHolder);
                console.log(errors); //does [] on first submit and then {errors: Array(2)}
            } 

//the array of error objects prints to the server console as:
[
  {
    value: 'J',
    msg: 'Name must be at least two letters long.',
    param: 'aName',
    location: 'body'
  },
  {
    value: 'JohnDoe@sit',
    msg: 'Must be a valid email',
    param: 'aEmail',
    location: 'body'
  }
]
```

I sincerely thank you for your time.

Comment: For two days you've been trying to figure out how to access elements of an array without success... ? Not sure where you are stuck. What's in the array?

Comment: Finding what's inside the array isn't difficult.  I have it returned from the server and printed to the console.  I am trying to get it rendered to the DOM.  It's this.[
  {
    value: 'J',
    msg: 'Name must be at least two letters long.',
    param: 'aName',
    location: 'body'
  },
  {
    value: 'JohnDoe@sit',
    msg: 'Must be a valid email',
    param: 'aEmail',
    location: 'body'
  }
]

Comment: Same way you would render any state to the dom with react. Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-rain-rffi4t?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: For future reference you should probably have a read at [ask] and [mre]. It's completely pointless to include all the code you have in your question if the actual problem is "how to render state to the DOM". It just makes the question really hard to understand and answer. Always reduce it to the simplest form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to showing express-validator errors in the DOM, helped greatly by super.  First, I set a useState for the error:

```
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({errors: []});
```

Then looked for a !response.ok object for the POST request and set that to the setErrors state.

```
        const response = await fetch("http://path", {    
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {     // if there is !response.ok object...
                return response.json();
            } 
        }).then(jsonData => {
            console.log("Error response object is:", jsonData);  
            setErrors(jsonData);  
        });
```

finally, to get it to show in the rendered JSX, I set a conditional to execute a map on the response object if it exists

```
{errors && errors.errors.map((err, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
        {err.msg}
    </div>
))}
```

Thanks.